# Is there a way to overwrite an html file dynamically in a phone gap project?

Tags: ios, cordova

So, my cohorts and I have been doing some development with Phonegap +jQueryMobile for an application we've been planning to rollout. We switched off doing this natively for iOS and Android, since its mostly html anyway, and phone gap seemed like a great way to do this without having to write a whole bunch of platform specific code (although we're more or less newbs when it comes to this type of development.)

Previously, all the html, javascript, etc, was going to be housed in the app itself. For the most part, this seemed to work for us, and we advanced our design/testing/etc accordingly. However, things have changed in our approach. For each of our customers (once they go through a log-in/authentication) has a 'starting' html file (essentially *'their'* index.html) that is specific to said customer. This was different from before where everyone had the same files.

Now I've played around with storing certain scripts on the web server to try and off-set opening the html running on the server, but it's not really that useful when trying to integrate some of the functionality like the camera or some of the other plugins we're trying to use. It's essentially a form-based application, so this is the ONLY file that will change from customer to customer. Also, this will **not** be something that changes frequently. For the most part, it will be setup for a customer **ONCE AND ONLY ONCE**, and it truly is unlikely to change.

Is there a way to more or less pull down this html file from a web server to replace the one that is stored internally in the app, and then load that version? Would doing something like that (if its even possible) violate Apple's or Google's App guidelines? Or is what I'm describing not even possible in the framework?

The only other thing I can think of would be to change the stored 'index.html' file to not load any of the form itself, but rather make ajax (or equivalent) calls to do so, but I've been told by our developer working the web design side of things that it would be a huge pain.

Any insight/knowledge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this (I don't quite understand why), I think your best bet is to go the AJAX route. At least Apple does not look kindly on applications that update themselves without going through the App Store submission process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same index.html for all and a script config.js that be the responsible of load/unload resources/html of each user at app start.

All you need to do then is save that config JSON values in localstorage and go.